# Visibility of the ContextMenu item does not change with DataTrigger in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make the menu item Visible/Collapsed as and when the property CanUserAddRows changes.

This is my Xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataGridSrc}">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="RowMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
      <MenuItem Header="Insert Row" >
        <MenuItem.Style>
          <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding CanUserAddRows}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </MenuItem.Style>
      </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

My UserControl

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    CanUserAddRows = false;
}
```

Why is the Menu Item still Visible?

Comment: what will be the initial value of CanUserAddRows ?

Comment: Did you try `Hidden` instead of `Collapsed`?

Comment: @Joseph I just have a getter and setter for CanUserAddRows. I set it in the constructor.

Comment: @LightBulb Yes. I tried hidden as well. Doesn't work.

Comment: `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` is incorrect, try `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}`

Comment: @MikeEason Changed the RelativeSource. It still does not work. I'm stumped.

Comment: @nan `PlacementTarget.DataContext` This too doesn't look right. `DataContext.SomePropertyName` would probably work.

Comment: I removed the DataContext from the Context Menu since I'm setting it in the constructor. It is still not working :(

Comment: It works if the ContextMenu belongs to the DataGrid, so it must be something to do with applying the row style.

Comment: did you call PropertyChanged() after you change CanUserAddRows's value?

Comment: Do you see any binding warnings in the VS output window when you right click the grid rows?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue and @MikeEason's solution worked for me. Just walk back to the parent UserControl, assuming that's what your DataGrid lives in. Did you leave the placement target in though? This isn't needed, so it should read `<ContextMenu ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">`.

Comment: Another option is to give a name to the UserControl, and add that to the binding: <DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding CanUserAddRows, ElementName="NameYouPicked"}" Value="False">